# How to remove duplicacy receiving for subscriber cluster in pubsub

Tags: redis, rabbitmq

I am thinking how to remove duplicacy for subscriber cluster in pubsub, for example:
There is a service called email, which should send welcome emails after user signing up. By using pub/sub, email service shall listen a event called "signedUp" which will be triggered each time user sign up. However, how about if I have 2 email services to balance? Without any special efforts, I think two welcome emails will be sent out. So how to solve this issue?

I prefer redis as pubsub server for simplicity, or rabbitmq if redis doesn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do it in redis. But in rabbitmq, it can, let me explain below:

Rabbitmq has a separate stuff called 'exchange' from queue. So server publish a message to exchange, client can create queues to bind to the exchange. Therefore, instances from one services can create the same queue to bind with exchange, by doing that exchange will delivery message to the queue once and handled by only one instance once.

Account service:

```
channel.assertExchange(‘signedUp’, 'fanout')
channel.publish(ex, '', new Buffer(message)
```

Email service:

```
let queue = channmel.assertQueue(‘email’);
channel.bindQueue(queue, 'signedUp'); // bind this queue to exchange
ch.consume(queue, logMessage)
```

By given a queue name in email service, no matter how many email services started, the published message (signedUp in this case) will be handled by one and ONLY ONE email service.